# Code Smells: изменение текущего экземпляра класса

Tags: java, ооп, конструктор, полиморфизм, рефакторинг

У меня есть класс `Person`. Данный класс абсурдный и служит только для визуализации проблемы.

```
public class Person {
    private int age;
    private String name;

    public Person(int age, String name){
        this.age=age;
        this.name=name;
    }

    public void printPersonInformation(){
        System.out.println("Name: "+name+"  Age: "+age);
    }

    public Person createRandomPerson(){
        return new Person(new Random().nextInt(50)+1,name);
    }
}
```

В `Test` я создаю екземляр класса, вывожу его и потому запускаю метод создания рандомного "Андрея", который возвращает новый екземпляр класса `Person` и тоже его вывожу в консоль и все отлично.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person person = new Person(12,"Andrew");
        person.printPersonInformation();

        Person person1 = person.createRandomPerson();
        person1.printPersonInformation();
    }
}
```

Как мне быть в моей проблеме: я бы хотел чтобы метод `createRandomPerson` изменял текущий объект, а не создавал новый. При этом нижеприведенное решение мне не подходит:

```
 public void createRandomPerson(){
        age = new Random().nextInt(50)+1;
     }
```

Не подходит, потому что в моем реальном проекте подобных методов больше 10, и переписывать в них конструктор (довольно емкий) каждый раз, мне кажется неразумно.

Comment: Вам нужно при помощи `createRandomPerson()` отдавать на верх существующего персонажа с одиним, рандомно измененным полем. Зачем переписывать конструктор, если нужно добавлять только данный метод?

Comment: Вообще для изменения свойств объекта существуют сеттеры

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как насчет:

```
public Person createRandomPerson() {
    age = new Random().nextInt(50) + 1;
    return this;
}
```